# Why only last character of the string in Angular async pipe binding is shown?

Tags: angular, rxjs

component.html:

```
<div *ngIf="!isWaiting">
  <h2>LOGIN</h2>
  <p>{{ message | async }}</p>
  <div *ngIf="!(isLoggedIn | async)">
    <button (click)="login()">{{'StrLogin' | translate}}</button>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="(isLoggedIn | async)">
    <button (click)="logout()">{{'StrLogout' | translate}}</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div *ngIf="isWaiting">
  <p>initializing</p>
</div>
```

component.ts

```
  message: Observable<string>;

  login(name : string, password : string): void {
    this.message = this.tokenService.login(name, password)
    .pipe(
      map((token) => {
        console.debug('login succeeded: %s', JSON.stringify(token));
        return 'success';
      }),
      catchError(err => {
        console.debug('login failed: %s', JSON.stringify(err));
        return 'failed';
      })
    );
  }
```

When this fails only the letter 'd' (of the 'failed') is displayed. If I change it to:

```
      catchError(err => {
        console.debug('login failed: %s', JSON.stringify(err));
        return '123';
      })
```

it displays 3.

Comment: try `return of('failed');` and you might want to add a `shareReplay(1)` operator if you're going to use this in a template. Otherwise it might login again when the template is updated.

Comment: Thanks! it worked. please write an answer and i accept it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `catchError()` operator expects the callback function to return an observable. I'm not sure why it renders `3` but most likely the string was converted into an observable array that emits each character in sequence.

https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/catchError.ts#L90

```
      catchError(err => {
        console.debug('login failed: %s', JSON.stringify(err));
        return of('failed');
      })
```

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/error_handling/catch.html

When using the `async` pipe in templates. Keep in mind that it will call *subscribe* if the DOM is mutated by a `*ngIf` higher up. So if the observable is sourced from an HTTP request, then add a `shareReplay(1)` operator and only use the same object reference in the template.

Comment: it makes sense. it emits d or 3 last depending on the string. and that is displayed. thanks for explanation.

Comment: @charm there have been a few questions from people who use `return of()` in `catchError()`. This generally isn't what you want, because it forces the observable to immediately complete. `of()` without arguments create an observable that emits nothing, and any operators after `catchError()` will not be executed. Just something to remember.